# randomforest variable importance: results of mlr3 is different from randomForest packages

Tags: random-forest, mlr3

i want to know why  the results are different?
Thanks for the help!

#### mlr3

```r
library(mlr3)
library(mlr3verse)
library(mlr3learners)
library(randomForest)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)

tasks = as_task_classif(iris, target = 'Species')
learners = lrn("classif.randomForest", predict_type = 
"prob",importance= c('gini'))
set.seed(123, kind = "Mersenne-Twister")

mlr3_result = learners$train(tasks)
mlr3_result$model
Call:
 randomForest(formula = formula, data = data, classwt = classwt,      cutoff = cutoff, importance = TRUE) 
               Type of random forest: classification
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 2

        OOB estimate of  error rate: 4%
Confusion matrix:
           setosa versicolor virginica class.error
setosa         50          0         0        0.00
versicolor      0         47         3        0.06
virginica       0          3        47        0.06

a$model$importance

   setosa  versicolor   virginica MeanDecreaseAccuracy MeanDecreaseGini
Petal.Length 0.335345171 0.307701242 0.294076163          0.310261341        43.088229
Petal.Width  0.330789167 0.311838647 0.273864031          0.303464596        44.258135
Sepal.Length 0.037133413 0.020715911 0.042752581          0.034013485         9.715093
Sepal.Width  0.008714192 0.004354224 0.008025792          0.006962512         2.238209
```

#### randomForest

```r
set.seed(123, kind = "Mersenne-Twister")
randomForest_result <- randomForest(iris[,1:4], 
                    iris$Species, 
                    importance = TRUE)
randomForest_result

Call:
 randomForest(x = iris[1:4], y = iris$Species, importance = TRUE) 
               Type of random forest: classification
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 2

        OOB estimate of  error rate: 4.67%
Confusion matrix:
           setosa versicolor virginica class.error
setosa         50          0         0        0.00
versicolor      0         47         3        0.06
virginica       0          4        46        0.08

randomForest_result[["importance"]]
 setosa  versicolor   virginica MeanDecreaseAccuracy MeanDecreaseGini
Sepal.Length 0.036131008 0.023774906 0.038354330          0.033578769         9.798189
Sepal.Width  0.008306837 0.001895114 0.007878582          0.006106488         2.236535
Petal.Length 0.328732260 0.308242048 0.293766472          0.307467294        43.093269
Petal.Width  0.337599283 0.315079112 0.267375505          0.303321451        44.042372
```

#### tidymodels

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
set.seed(123, kind = "Mersenne-Twister")
tidy_results = rand_forest(mode = "classification",) %>%
  set_engine("randomForest",importance = T) %>%
  fit(
    Species ~.,
    data = iris
  )
tidy_results

Call:
 randomForest(x = maybe_data_frame(x), y = y, importance = ~T) 
               Type of random forest: classification
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 2

        OOB estimate of  error rate: 4.67%
Confusion matrix:
           setosa versicolor virginica class.error
setosa         50          0         0        0.00
versicolor      0         47         3        0.06
virginica       0          4        46        0.08

tidy_results[["fit"]][["importance"]]
 setosa  versicolor   virginica MeanDecreaseAccuracy MeanDecreaseGini
Sepal.Length 0.036131008 0.023774906 0.038354330          0.033578769         9.798189
Sepal.Width  0.008306837 0.001895114 0.007878582          0.006106488         2.236535
Petal.Length 0.328732260 0.308242048 0.293766472          0.307467294        43.093269
Petal.Width  0.337599283 0.315079112 0.267375505          0.303321451        44.042372
```

tidymodels and randomForest have the same results, but mlr3 and randomForest not, setting the seed does not yield the same results!
I make some mistakes in code? I feel confused...

randomForest:4.7.1.1
mlr3:0.17.0
tidymodels:1.1.1